# Regex: how to add a capture group?

Tags: php, regex

I currently have [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/fOU0BK/4):

```
\[(?:\w+\*?\s+)?([^][]+)]
```

I want to add another capture group, so I can capture the text value before the groups.

For example:

```
Je naam (verplicht) [text* your-test]
```

My regex currently captures `[text* your-test]`. I want to add another group that captures the "`Je naam (verplicht)`" part.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex with additional capture group:

```
([^][\h]+(?:\h+[^][\h]+)*)?\h+\[(?:\w+\*?\h+)?([^][]+)]
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fOU0BK/6)

- `([^][\h]+(?:\h+[^][\h]+)*)?` is new optional capture group that matches and captures text before `[...]` into a separate group.
- `[^][\h]+` matches 1 or more of any character that is not `[`, `]` and whitespace.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It works perfectly in a sandbox, however when I try it in my application the capture group only returns empty arrays, while the text/string is identical. The other capture groups do still work. Any ideas why that's happening?

Comment: If text is identical then regex should work in any PHP code.

Comment: be aware that in php \ escapes certain characters, so you'll need to douple escape them (or just all to be sure). `'/([^][\\h]+(?:\\h+[^][\\h]+)*)?\\h+\\[(?:\\w+\\*?\\h+)?([^][]+)]/'`

Comment: I have asked this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62431649/regex-expression-on-strstr-function-returns-empty-capture-group

Comment: Thanks, let me check there.